# Como declarar uma função em forma de arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Como declarar a função abaixo como arrow function no javascript ecma 6 e depois chama-la? Atualmente eu a utilizo assim e não sei como deixa funcionando sem o "function" na frente.

```js
execSQLQuery('DELETE FROM Usuarios WHERE idUser=' + parseInt(req.params.id), res);


function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, res){
       const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        port     : 3306,
        user     : 'joao',
        password : '123',
        database : 'dadosD'
    })   
    connection.query(sqlQry, (error, results, fields)=>{
        if(error) 
          res.json(error);
        else
          res.json(results);
        connection.end();
        console.log('executou!');
    })
  };
```

Comment: Por que quer declarar essa função como arrow function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não creio que haja necessidade de fazer isso, não fará diferença alguma no código. Porém...

Arrow functions são funções anônimas, ou seja, elas não tem nome. Para identificá-las, você precisa atribuir ela a algum label, no caso uma variável.

Desse jeito:

```js
const execSQLQuery = (sqlQry, res) => {
...
};
```

Porém, se fizer isso, terá um `ReferenceError`, visto que declarações `let` ou `const` não tem *hoisting*. Logo, terás que mover a declaração para antes da invocação da mesma. No caso:

```js
const execSQLQuery = (sqlQry, res) => {
...
};

execSQLQuery('DELETE FROM Usuarios WHERE idUser=' + parseInt(req.params.id), res);
```

(Note que agora está abaixo)

Comment: Boa Luis, estou estudando profundamente o Ecma6 e você respondeu muito bem, era exatamente isso que eu precisava saber, show de bola! Obrigado!